# iOS Safari Overscrolling: Pulling down vs. bouncing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile-safari

My team and me are developing a web application which bears a fixed header, that doesn't scroll.

In order to handle overscrolling on iOS, we need to detect scrolling in negative direction and reposition the fixed header as static again to make it scroll along with the rest of the page.
We do this by binding a jQuery scroll handler to `window`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 0) {
        // position static header postioning in order
        // let the header behave correctly when overscrolling
    }
});
```

This works well, when the page is manually pulled (dragged) down.
But as every iOS user knows, when scrolling the page from a downwards position with speed up again, it bounces (overscrolls), once it reaches its top.

In this case, our scroll handling doesn't work.

At the moment I can imagine two reasons, why this different behaviour occurs:

- Rapid scrolling upwards, and making a page bounce, is too fast for Safari's JS engine to ensure a fluid handling
- Is bouncing when scrolling upwards technically the same as manually pulling down a webpage? In respect to `$(window).scrollTop()` ?

Has anybody some hints how to make my scroll handling work in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `position:fixed` in CSS isn't working for you, then you should try to make a draw loop, and every single time that loop runs, you place  a horizontal offset that is equal to how far your user has scrolled.

Basically, your JS should look like this if CSS doesn't work:

```
var head = document.getElementById("header");
//head now has our header
head.style.position = "relative";
//and now, we can manipulate it's position
function draw(){
    head.style.top = window.pageYOffset;
    //all that's left to do is do this each and every frame.
}
```

And if you don't know how to make a draw loop, here's the code:

```
var frameRate = 60;
var frameCounter = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    return function(){
        counter ++;
        if(counter > frameRate/1000){
            counter -= frameRate/1000;
            draw();
        }
    }
})();
setInterval(frameCounter, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since this draw loop is permanently running, even if the page is not scrolling, don't you think it might cause performance issues?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fairly better than doing it with pure CSS. It seems as if setting just CSS classes to trigger optical changes doesn't work quick enough, when scrolling quickly. Still I'd appreciate some hint on performance aspects...

Comment: @Windwalker There might be more code required, like detecting when the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved in iOS 9.3 New meta tag option

```
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width,shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: See : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH10-SW8

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where is the reference to (over)scrolling / bouncing?